# How do calculate cash flow for every week for 5 years?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate cash flow for every week for 5 years. 
The source table:

```
ID    WeekNumber    DayTime     Dollars
1     1             2012-01-01  10
2     1             2012-01-02  10
3     2             2012-01-08  20
....
353   1             2013-01-01  30
```

Table contains days for 5 years day by day. WeekNumber begins from the number 1 for every year.

In conclusion, view should looks like:

```
WeekNumber    CashFlow
1             (sum)
2             (sum)
3             (sum)
....
1             (sum)
2             (sum)
3             (sum)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT *, 
CashFlow = (SELECT SUM(X.TotalSum) as TT 
            FROM (SELECT WeekNumber, SUM(Dollars) as TotalSum 
                  FROM dbo.Temp  
                  GROUP BY WeekNumber) X 
            WHERE X.WeekNumber <= Y.WeekNumber) 
FROM(SELECT WeekNumber,  SUM(Dollars) as TotalSum 
     FROM dbo.Temp  
     GROUP BY WeekNumber) Y 
ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC
```

For one year it returns correct numbers, but for 5 years it returns only 53 rows contain sum of cash flow for every week in every year.

Have you any ideas how can I improve it for getting a needed result?

Comment: Views (like Tables) have no *inherent* order. So unless you add an additional column to indicate *which year* each row belongs to, even if we get your desired output there would be no means to distinguish which of the 5 `WeekNumber` 1 rows corresponds to each year. If you accept the need to include the year column then it becomes trivial to include that in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Extract year from DayTime column and group by Year(Daytime) and weeknumber and sum your amount.

Answer (score 1):

You need to a Year column to split totals for each year, you can use the DateTime column wrapped in a [Year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql) function to do this on the fly

```
SELECT 
  WeekNumber, Year = YEAR(DayTime), CashFlow = SUM(Dollars) 
From InsertFromExel.dbo.Temp
Group By
   WeekNumber, YEAR(DayTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your described table and what you want as output:
(edit: If you want your exact output remove the year part from SELECT)

```
SELECT YEAR(DayTime) as Year, WeekNumber, SUM(Dollars) as CashFlow
FROM InsertFromExel.dbo.Temp
GROUP BY WeekNumber, YEAR(DayTime)
ORDER BY Year asc, WeekNumber asc
```

Group By YEAR(DayTime) and WeekNumber will Merge all rows where both of these attributes match and yield a single result row. Via SUM(Dollars) all Dollars are added for each of those matches and provide the sum as output for the respective result row. The ORDER BY sorts first by year then by week (asc = ascending).

Edit: added ORDER BY part.

Comment: `From table`? `GroupBy`? Can you post code that would actually work? And perhaps explain what you changed, show sample input and output data, and how it answers the question, etc.

Comment: didnt see table name and wrote GROUP BY wrong, sry - edited

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

is this usefull

```
    create table #tmp (ID Int, weeknumber int, DayTime DATETIME,Dollars int)

    insert into #tmp values(1,1,'2012-01-01',10)
    insert into #tmp values(1,1,'2012-01-02',10)

    insert into #tmp values(1,2,'2012-01-08',20)
    insert into #tmp values(1,2,'2012-01-09',30)

    insert into #tmp values(1,3,'2012-01-15',90)
    insert into #tmp values(1,3,'2012-01-16',30)

    insert into #tmp values(1,1,'2013-01-01',30)
    insert into #tmp values(1,1,'2013-01-02',10)

    insert into #tmp values(1,2,'2013-01-08',40)
    insert into #tmp values(1,2,'2013-01-09',20)

    insert into #tmp values(1,3,'2013-01-15',60)
    insert into #tmp values(1,3,'2013-01-16',70)


    select weeknumber,Sum(Dollars) As Cashflow from #tmp
    Group by Year(DayTime),weeknumber
    order by Year(DayTime),weeknumber

    drop table #tmp
```